# JavaScript Why is s=5 shown in strict mode

Tags: javascript

```js
   "use strict"    
    function a(s){
        console.log(s)
    }
    a(5);
```

JavaScript does not implicitly declare variables in strict mode. How does s get a value if s is not declared

Comment: But it _is_ declared, as a parameter of function `a`. All function parameters are variables local to their function.

Comment: If `s` was to be considered undeclared, then using string mode would disallow ANY function that takes parameters. You would not be able to call stuff like `parseInt` or even `console.log`

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that `s` actually *is* declared. But it's not just a normal variable declared with `var`, but a parameter of the function which is defined with the function. The `console.log` will not execute until the `a(5)` call, and as soon as you call `a(5)` or even simply `a()` you are initializing the `s` parameter with a value which can be `5` in this case or `undefined`, or anything else. But again, it *is* declared so no errors should be expected neither in the strict mode nor in non-strict mode.